# Are questions related to health technology assessment and health economics off topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm a mod from Economics.SE and thought it would be better to ask questions relating to health technology assessment and cost effectiveness analysis here since these arent the usual questions non health economists work with.

I'm wondering if questions relating to health technology assessment and cost effectiveness analysis are on topic for this community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think such questions can be on topic. If you look at [What topics can I ask about here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you'll see this (**emphasis is mine**):

> If your question is about...
>
> - clinical guidelines
> - **disease prevention and management**
> - human physiology and pathophysiology
> - pharmacology
> - diagnostic and prognostic methods
> - **public health**
> - medical research
>
> ... then this is the right place to ask.

Although that list doesn't specifically include health technology and economic issues, I think those fall under the broad headings I've bolded. For example, if multiple treatments are available for a disease, and they vary significantly in cost, then knowing their cost effectiveness would certainly be germane to making a decision on which will be approved. And if it's the entity that makes those decisions in your country, then clearly it's a public health issue and therefore on topic here.

I did get the sense that you thought such analyses were possibly useless because they only apply to a specific treatment pathway, but I think the first answer you got on your question addresses that.

But as I commented on your question, it does need to show a little prior research. I would think you're actually in a better position to judge what that would entail than we are. Who reads the reports you create, for example?

Comment: Hey Carey, thanks for the clarification. Most HTA reports in my country are sent further up the decision making pipeline where  managers compare this proposal to the many others that are received. I don't support the literature review portion of these reports so my appreciation for them is not as great as my colleagues who have a clinical background.